# Create multiple tasks, don't await them, but have them run sequentially

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I'm trying to have 2 tasks run one after the other, but I don't want to wait for them to finish since I'll be doing that later.
Initially I had an implementation with `ContinueWith` but the double `await` was bothering me and I don't see `Unwrap()` as a significant improvement.

I decided to do a PoC to create the 2 tasks separately and have another task dispatched to manage them while I return the 2 initial tasks but weirdly the tasks become marked as completed as soon as I hit the `await Task.Delay()` which basically means that in reality they're running concurrently.
This is the code:

```
var task1 = new Task(async ()=>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 Start");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 STOP");
});
var task2 = new Task(async () => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task2 Start");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task2 STOP");
});
var taskParent = Task.Run(async () => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("starting 1");
    task1.Start();
    await task1;
    Console.WriteLine("starting 2");
    task2.Start();
    await task2;
});

Console.WriteLine("BEGIN await parent");
await taskParent;
Console.WriteLine("END await parent");
```

and the output is

```
BEGIN await parent
starting 1
Task1 Start
starting 2
Task2 Start
END await parent
Task2 STOP
Task1 STOP
```

So I go from my desire to have task2 begin after `task1` to it finishing before `task1` does. I can't see a reason why calling `await Task.Delay` would mark the tasks as complete. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**
To simplify my requirements since there seems to be a bit of confusion.
The tasks must be returned before they are awaited, and the second task must run after the first.
Some other thread will want the result later on and if it is completed fine if not it will await.
I need to be able to await the second task and expect that the first one is executed before the second one.

Comment: You may use some single task TaskScheduler

Comment: You should check the [Task.ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen he wrote that he use it  already but for some reasons he don't want it (*Initially I had an implementation with ContinueWith but the double await was bothering me and I don't see Unwrap() as a significant improvement.*)

Comment: @Selvin Bad reading.. sorry..

Comment: @Stevie tasks aren't threads. There's *never* any good reason to use the task constructor. You can't control execution by calling `Start()`. A Task is just a function call that will be scheduled for execution on a threadpool thread. There's no guarantee that independent tasks will execute or complete in the order they were created.

Comment: @Stevie why don't you want to use `await`? There's no need for double awaits and unwraps. If you don't want to await the task sequence right now, put them in a separate async method, store the task it returns and wait for it whenever you want

Comment: The main problem is that `new Task()` only accepts an `Action` as parameter. Do the returned task disappears into the void and is not awaited. So the task `task1` is finished where the await starts and it exits the action.

Comment: *"the second task must run after the first"* -- Could you explain the reason? Does the second task have some dependency on the first task? Does it need the result of the first task? Do they both need a resource that can be used by only one task at a time? We might be able to suggest an alternative design, that doesn't involve awkward `Task` constructors, if we have a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could also consider posting a new question, asking "This is what I want to do. How can I do it?". The current question is more about "This is my solution to a problem. Why my solution doesn't work?".

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias The first task sets up a desired state on a different machine. It doesn't need an actual result it just needs the actions to happen in the correct order.

I could repost the question but it's actually what I'm going for. I already had a solution, but I wanted the code to look prettier. Then I got hit with a behavior that I really didn't expect and I wanted to understand it better. Or I wanted to know what was wrong in the way I thought it out.

Comment: I see. What if the first task fails? How this should affect the second task? Should the second task propagate the exception thrown by the first task?

Comment: it was a PoC, I figured I could always add error handling later on. Adding it in the post would have probably confused things further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll hear frequently that using the `Task` constructor is not recommended, and it's a wise advice. It's easier to create a [`Func<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1), and invoke it when you want to start the task, and it's also safer. The `Task` constructor has the same hidden gotchas with the [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method: it doesn't understand async delegates, and it requires to specify explicitly the scheduler when you start it. But if you know positively that the `Task` constructor is the best tool for your problem, here is how you can use it:

```
Task<Task> taskTask1 = new Task<Task>(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 Start");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 STOP");
});

Task<Task> taskTask2 = new Task<Task>(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task2 Start");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task2 STOP");
});

Task taskParent = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("starting 1");
    taskTask1.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
    await taskTask1.Unwrap();
    Console.WriteLine("starting 2");
    taskTask2.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
    await taskTask2.Unwrap();
});

Console.WriteLine("BEGIN await parent");
await taskParent;
Console.WriteLine("END await parent");
```

Output:

```
BEGIN await parent
starting 1
Task1 Start
Task1 STOP
starting 2
Task2 Start
Task2 STOP
END await parent
```

Notice that you don't need to `Unwrap` the `Task.Run`, because this method [understands async delegates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/), and does the unwrapping automatically for you.

Notice also the `TaskScheduler.Default` passed as argument to the `Start` method. Not specifying the scheduler makes your code depended on the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current`, and might generate warnings in the presence of the [CA2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) analyzer.

Comment: while it fixes the problem it brings back the annoyance of using either double await ```await await taskTask1``` or using unwrap ```await taskTask1.Unwrap()```.
It's still not clear why making a Task of Task solves the problem

Comment: @Stevie yea, it's not easy to explain why this happens. I have attempted to explain it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873465/how-to-declare-a-not-started-task-that-will-await-for-another-task/58876727#58876727) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659668/c-sharp-async-task-completes-before-its-finished/60664869#60664869). Basically asynchronous methods return `Task`s. So when you have a `Func<T>` parameter and you give it an asynchronous function as argument, the compiler resolves the `T` as `Task`. Think about it.

Answer (score 3):

Tasks aren't threads. There's never a good reason to create a task through its constructor and try to "start" it later. A Task is a Promise that something will complete in the future and may not even be executable. For example, `Task.Delay` uses a timer to signal a TaskCompletionSource.

It's impossible to control execution through `Start`, again because tasks arent' threads. `Start` only schedules a task for execution, it doesn't actually run it. There's no guarantee the tasks will run in the order they were scheduled.

`await` doesn't execute a task either, it *awaits* an already active task to complete, without blocking the calling thread. You don't need to await a task to make it execute. You only need to await it when you want to get its results, or wait for it to finish.

As for the question itself, it's unclear what the problem is. If the question is how to execute some async functions in sequence without awaiting the entire sequence, the easiest way would be to put them in their own async method, store its task in a variable and await it when needed :

```
async Task GetAnImageAsync()
{
    //Load a URL from DB using Dapper
    var url=await connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<string>("select top 1 URLs from Pictures");
    //Get the image
    var image=await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    //Save it
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("blah.jpg",image);
}

...

async Task DoSomethingElse()
{
    var imageTask=GetAnImageAsync();
    //Do some other work
    ...
    //Only await at the end
    await imageTask();
}
```

Comment: I'm not even sure what this is an answer to.
Start makes the task active, which means it can be awaited for a reason and not just lock the current thread.
Not sure what gives you the impression I don't understand what await does.
And the question is definitely not what you answered. I edited my initial question in hopes it clarifies the problem.

Comment: @Stevie the point is *tasks*, not await. `Start` is never used, for a reason. You'll never find it in any example or tutorial. In SO, you'll only find it as a problem, in questions. It gives you no more control over when a task starts than `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`. `Task.Start` simply registers a task (promise) for execution with a TaskScheduler. How a task is scheduled depends on the TaskScheduler used, not on when it's registered with the TaskScheduler. If you want tasks to run one after the other, you *must* use `ContinueWith` or `await`

Comment: If I don't use ```Start``` the task never becomes active, there's no point in awaiting it. It's just going to block the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in c# a task created is always running, therefore if you create task, and not awaiting it, then it will be running in separate thread most likely. Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

To archive sequential execution you either have to do a kind of scheduler for them or implement sequence on some sort of locking mechanism.

Continue with is the easiest method to guarantee that.

Comment: No, a task isn't always running. A task isn't a thread, it's a Promise that something will complete in the future. That something may not even be executable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "might complete in the future."

Comment: My wording may be bad here. What I wanted to say is by declaring a new task you don't have control of starting it, as it's assumed started. Therefore, if task is an asynchronous long running task it most likely be run on another thread, so the current one can continue on execution. There are corner cases, yes I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

Given that all task constructors accept `Action` or variants of thereof, doing

```
var task1 = new Task(async ()=>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 Start");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 STOP");
});

task1.Start();
await task1;
```

is not dissimilar to doing

```
void EntryPoint()
{
    CallAsync();
}

async void CallAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 Start");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 STOP");
}
```

The `CallAsync` from above will run until first suspension (`await Task.Delay(5000)`) upon which it registers a `Timer` callback and returns to the caller which promptly returns, completely unaware of any `async` semantics.

If the application is still alive by the time the `Timer` under `Task.Delay` fires, it will run the continuation based on current `TaskScheduler` and `SynchronizationContext` as usual, writing `Task1 STOP` to the console.

If you need to run tasks sequentially without awaiting them, either use `ContinueWith` or implement a custom `TaskScheduler` to do this for you.

Or even better, as suggested by @Panagiotis Kanavos, create a stand-alone async method which runs the sequence of tasks and await its result:

```
async Task PerformThingsAsync()
{
    var task = RunMyTasksAsync();

    // Do things

    await task;
}

async Task RunTasksAsync()
{
    await RunFistTaskAsync();
    await RunSecondTaskAsync();
    // ...
}
```